# Hibernate link between 2 persistence units?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0

my question is a bit tricky so I will try to make it as simple as possible:

I have two maven projects: ProjetA and ProjectB.

ProjectA has the following *persistence.xml* file:

```
<persistence-unit name="ProjectAUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.projectA.Client</class>
        <class>com.projectA.InterventionA</class>
    </persistence-unit>
```

InterventionA has a OneToOne relationship with the Client entity.

ProjectB has the following *persistence.xml* file:

```
<persistence-unit name="projectBUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.projectB.InterventionB</class>
        <class>com.projectB.InterventionOrder</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

InterventionB extends the InterventionA class (contained in a .jar dependency):

All 3 classes *InterventionA, InterventionB* and *Client* are defined in the same MySQL schema (schema1).

**BUT** InterventionB also has a @OneToOne relationship with the *InterventionOrder* entity defined in another MySQL schema (schema2).
    private InterventionOrder interventionOrder;

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.projectA.InterventionA.client references an unknown entity: com.projectA.Client
```

So here is my question: Is why I am trying to achieve even possible with Hibernate/Spring? if yes how? :-)
thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InterventionB has inherited the one-to-one relationship between itself and Client (from InterventionA). To be able to define a relationship the target entity must be mapped, in Project B Client is not mapped, hence the error. As Project B depends on Project A you can simply add the target entity to Project B's persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="projectBUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.projectB.InterventionB</class>
    <class>com.projectB.InterventionOrder</class>

    <class>com.projectA.Client</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: @russ-hayward : Thanks a lot Russ for your answer but I'm having another issue now: the com.projectB.InterventionOrder entity has the following relationship with Intervention: `@OneToOne(optional=false) @JoinColumn(name="ID_INTER") private Intervention intervention;` Causing the following exception: _"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'projectBPersistenceUnit.intervention' doesn't exist"`_. It should look for intervention in the ProjectA Persistence Unit instead. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: InterventionA is not mapped in ProjectB so Hibernate cannot map associations to it. I suspect that Hibernate is searching mapped classes to see which ones implement Intervention, finding InterventionB only, and using it. You may be able to fix it by mapping InterventionA in project B and then specifying @OneToOne(optional=false, targetEntity=InterventionA.class). If that doesn't work might be best to start a new question to see if anyone knows a solution.